# How do I spot the smallest negative number using swift

Tags: swift

OK,

Having a mental block here... I got a range of vectors

```
node 0 SCNVector3(x: 8.208711e-08, y: 0.0, z: -1.9389672) 
node 1 SCNVector3(x: -0.93896717, y: 0.0, z: -1.0000001) 
node 2 SCNVector3(x: -8.208711e-08, y: 0.0, z: -0.06103283) 
node 3 SCNVector3(x: 0.93896717, y: 0.0, z: -0.99999994) 
node 4 SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.93896717, z: -1.0) 
node 5 SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.93896717, z: -1.0)
```

And I want to select node2 since it has the smallest negative number. It's a stupid question, I know; I am sorry.

```
struct Sats {
    var theNode = SCNNode()
    var theIndex:Int = 7
}

if cubeNode != nil {
        cubeNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            let search = /face(\d+)/
            if let result = try? search.wholeMatch(in: node.name!) {
                print("node \(result.1) \(node.worldPosition) ")
                if node.worldPosition.z < -0.05 {
                    print("eureka \(theOne.theIndex)")
                    theOne.theNode = node
                    theOne.theIndex = Int(result.1)!
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are these vectors stored in an array, set or other data structure? (Do you have a code snippet?) Have you tried anything so far? How did it work out and where did you get stuck?

Comment: No, since I have to extract the vectors from a scene I do so in a loop.I could add them to array if it makes sense. I will add the code.

Comment: I assume you're filtering these nodes by some criteria (by name and by Z position?). If a node matches these criteria, you can add them to an array, then use `min(by:)` to pick the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your objects are in an array, you can use [`min(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/min(by:)). Like a lot of Swift's sorting methods it takes a block with two values, and you return TRUE if the second one is larger than the first:

```swift
myVectors.min { $0.x < $1.x }
```

The returned value is an optional – it's either the smallest value in the array, or `nil` if the array was empty.

Comment: Needed to ad abs() to this to get it to work